# Why does my for loop return only one result

Tags: javascript, jquery

The value of the search is supposed to append  to the nyt api and the for loop is supposed to list all the links. I'm only getting one result for some reason but when looked through console I see that there 100s of links.

```
function myFunction(){
var citySearch = $("#city").val();

var NYTurl = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=" + citySearch +
"$sort=newest&api-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

jQuery.getJSON(NYTurl, function (data){
    var headlines = $("#headlines")
    var contentUrl = data.response.docs
    for(var i = 0; i < contentUrl.length; i++ ){
        contentUrlLoop = contentUrl[i];
        headlines.html('<a href="'+contentUrlLoop.web_url+'">Link</a>' );
    }
    console.log(data)
})

return false;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`headlines.html(` assigns the passed HTML string to `headlines`'s inner HTML. So, on each iteration, you're overwriting whatever `headlines` had previously. Use `append` instead if you want to insert an `<a>` for every item in the response:

```
headlines.append('<a href="'+contentUrlLoop.web_url+'">Link</a>' );
```

Or, rather than making hundreds of DOM changes, you might consider coming up with a single HTML string and *then* `append`ing it:

```
jQuery.getJSON(NYTurl, function(data) {
  var headlines = $("#headlines");
  var contentUrl = data.response.docs;
  var htmlStr = contentUrl.reduce(
    (a, { web_url }) => a + '<a href="' + web_url + '">Link</a>',
    ''
  );
  headlines.html('<a href="' + contentUrlLoop.web_url + '">Link</a>');
});
```

(perhaps enclose them in `div`s as well so that each link is on a new line, or make the `a`s block, so that the HTML is readable)